# Measuring system calls per second in Linux

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, kernel

Is there a way to measure the total number of system calls per second on a Linux system?

strace gives counts, but only for a single process.
It looks like some versions of sar support this, but the one I have only shows context switches/sec or forks/sec.  I'm running a 2.6.9-89 based kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look into writing a [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) script.  There is even [an example](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/topsyssect.html) script that could be modified to meet your needs.

Comment: +1, very easy to do with SystemTap

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run strace for every process in your machines and afterwards count them ?

Comment: Running strace has a lot of overhead and I can't think of a way to catch short lived processes with this method.